# magento print friendly page for products

Tags: php, mysql, magento

In magento, is there already a way to do for a friendly print pages?

Just before I write my own block to do this, I wasn't sure if there was an default / existing one I can edit.... :)

Cheers

Shane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think I may be able to do this through a print css... Going to give it a go!

Yep used the defualt print.css - but changed it to look how I wanted, job done!

Comment: Magento already has a print CSS in place which works quite well, especially for the admin. Having a separate print page is a waste of effort.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any default way for printer friendly products in Magento. You need to write your own code to do so.

This link might help:-

<del>http://ajmaltash.wordpress.com/2010/05/23/print-link-on-product-detail-page-magento-1-4-0-1/</del> [ LINK NOT WORKING ]

**Update:**

Here is a **FREE Magento Extension** to [Print Product & Shopping Cart Page](https://marketplace.magento.com/chapagain-chapagain-clearprint.html)

Comment: That link now leads to a 404 page, any chance there is another copy of that anywhere?

Comment: This was a popular article for printer friendly products. I could not find it's copy anywhere.

Comment: @Rathinam Magento Connect has moved to Magento Marketplace. I have recently submitted the extension to Magento Marketplace. It will be live when they review and accept the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know, although there is a print.css.

There are a few ways I can think of to go about it, and none of them are built-in
1) Make your own site-specific print.css (good)
2) Make your own button to display / hide elements with JS (ugly)
3) Write your own Magento code to generate a printable page (difficult)
4) Get an extension -there are several PDF generators out there, and also a newer extension called CleanPrint that doesn't use PDF's

Answer (score 0):

Printing my magento pages were coming out as links/text, no images. I did go to skin>frontend>"theme">default>css>"print.css" and found that if I commented out everything after "@media print {" all the way to the closing bracket "}", it printed everything perfectly. I'll add the code that I'm using now without the commented out code below.

```
/* ======================================================================================= */

/* Boilerplate Print CSS  ========================START=========================== */

/*
* Media queries for responsive design
* These follow after primary styles so they will successfully override.
*/

@media all and (orientation:portrait) {
 /* Style adjustments for portrait mode goes here */

}

@media all and (orientation:landscape) {
  /* Style adjustments for landscape mode goes here */

}

/* Grade-A Mobile Browsers (Opera Mobile, iPhone Safari, Android Chrome)
  Consider this: www.cloudfour.com/css-media-query-for-mobile-is-fools-gold/ */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

  /* Uncomment if you don't want iOS and WinMobile to mobile-optimize the text for you
     j.mp/textsizeadjust
  html { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:none; } */
}

/*
 * print styles
 * inlined to avoid required HTTP connection www.phpied.com/delay-loading-your-print-css/
 */

/* Boilerplate Print CSS =========================END============================ */
```

Hope this helps…