# Magento print page layout

Tags: magento, layout, view, printing, product

I'm trying to make a print page on the product view on magento.
I want when I click on the button to generate a pop where I will have name, some images, description, brand ....

---

I don;t want to change the style/css deseign o the print page...
I want exactly like on this page http://tinyurl.com/btsdobf   click on the **Printeaza pagina** to see it in action.
I want to put more attributs on print page layout...

Comment: you can edit the layout of the print page see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857587/magento-print-friendly-page-for-prodcuts

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the layout of your print page by customizing the `print.css` file in your theme.

See this question: [magento print friendly page for products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857587/magento-print-friendly-page-for-prodcuts)

Answer (score 0):

you mean `javascript:window.print();` ?

style to control page design:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://demo3.magentocommerce.com/skin/frontend/default/default/css/print.css" media="print" />`